How can I schedule a function/callback to be executed by a callback group from another callback group?
Basically:

While inside callback group A or B of a node. I need a way to add any callback fun (a python function) to a (MutuallyExclusive) callback group C, then have it executed by C once.
Details:

Let's say I have two services' callback taking 1 second in callback group A and B. Both need to execute simultaneously.
From within those long callback A and B, I want to run my short function fun. But several fun functions canNOT execute simultaneously, because fun reads/writes the same data and this creates race conditions. So I want to execute all instances of my function fun in a MutuallyExclusive callback group C, this way fun will never create a race condition.
I also have other subscribers who's callback would create race conditions with fun, so those also need to be in callback group C. That is why I did not use a flag or asyncio, it would create a huge mess every time I use this callback group C.
My solution:

After searching how to do that for days, I came up with this very ugly implementation. It honestly surprises me that I cannot simply add a custom function in the queue of a callback group. Hence why I am asking here.
In my code, I used the GuardCondition which I do not understand, but it works. I also though of using Future.done_callback but a callback group cannot be assigned to a Future and its done_callback.
def execute_in_cbk_group(
    self, fun: Callable, callback_group: Optional[CallbackGroup] = None
) -> Tuple[Future, GuardCondition]:
    """Executes the given function by adding it as a callback to a callback_group.

    Args:
        fun - function: function to execute
        callback_group - CallbackGroup: callback group in which to execute the function
    Returns:
        future: holds the future results
        quardian: the guard condition object in the callback_group
    """
    future = Future()

    def fun_with_future():
        if not future.done():  # guardian triggers several times, idk why.
            # so this condition protects this mess from repeting itselfs randomly
            result = fun()
            future.set_result(result)
            return result

    # guardian will execute fun_with_future inside of callback_group
    guardian = self.create_guard_condition(fun_with_future, callback_group)
    guardian.trigger()
    future.add_done_callback(lambda result: self.destroy_guard_condition(guardian))
    return future, guardian


I have two major problems with this code (aside from the fact that whole thing is sketchy):

Trigger is executed once, but the callback fun_with_future executes several times (this happens rarely, like 1% of the time in my code). The check if not future.done(): is here to avoid that, but I am very far from proud of this solution.
future.add_done_callback(lambda result: self.destroy_guard_condition(guardian)) is here to destroy the GuardCondition (if I don't, the problem of the previous point happens more often). The problem here is that this destroy is not part of callback group C, but part of the long blocking A or B. So it can only clean the GuarCondition several seconds after fun executes.

How should I write this execute_in_cbk_group function properly?

I edited the code in case anyone needs it. I changed guardian.destroy() to self.destroy_guard_condition(guardian). Previously the guardian was never destroyed creating high CPU usage.
